# Parsing a PowerShell PSCustomObject XML with Excel VBS

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, vbscript

I spent hours trying to find my own solution, but failed :(
All I want to do is Read in the XML and create a Muti-Layered-Array or ArrayList.

This is an example of the output from Powershell..

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Selected.System.String</T>
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <I32 N="RefNum">1</I32>
      <S N="Name">MyVMName</S>
      <S N="Type">VM</S>
      <!-- Additional properties -->
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <!-- Additional objects -->
</Objs>
```

This is one of many attempts but feel free to tear it apart.

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False

' Load the PowerShell XML content
xmlDoc.Load "your_powershell_xml_file.xml"

If xmlDoc.ParseError = 0 Then
    ' Use the namespace in XPath queries
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ps='http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04'"

    ' Select all PSCustomObject elements
    Set customObjects = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ps:Obj[TN/T='System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject']")

    ' Iterate through PSCustomObject elements
    For Each customObject In customObjects
        ' Access properties within the PSCustomObject
        RefNum = customObject.SelectSingleNode("MS/I32[@N='RefNum']").Text
        Name = customObject.SelectSingleNode("MS/S[@N='Name']").Text
        Type = customObject.SelectSingleNode("MS/S[@N='Type']").Text

        ' Display the parsed properties
        WScript.Echo "RefNum: " & RefNum
        WScript.Echo "Name: " & Name
        WScript.Echo "Type: " & Type
    Next
Else
    ' Handle XML parsing error
    WScript.Echo "Error loading PowerShell XML: " & xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason
End If
```

Any Help to using VBS Reading in the XML Made from Powershell and populate a a Muti-Layered-Array or ArrayList.
It fails at "xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ps:Obj[TN/T='System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject']")"

Comment: Is the ultimate goal to populate an Excel spreadsheet (note that Excel uses VBA, not VBScript)? If so, it may be easier to use PowerShell, which understands the XML format (CLIXML) natively.

Comment: Wat does "if fails" mean? Which error do you get? I think your xpath expression is off.

Comment: I will be adding some of the data to a sheet.  so, I need to fiddle with it first.  What fails is the customObjects  has no customObject in the for each.  it just drops thru

Comment: The XML is a Master Dataset that is used by many more PowerShell programs so really can't change it.  I could create CSV for that matter.  but at this point it's a challenge.  LOL   This should not be this hard..

Comment: the user that will be using the excel has no auth to use PowerShell.   everything will have to be done in Excel and vbs...  Unless I misunderstand what you mean by 'Import-CliXml' it is a cmdlet used in PowerShell.  I thought of trying to do a PowerShell cmd in VBS :P to do that.  but I get a permissions error without being elevated.

Comment: I think all I need to do is work out the correct customObjects.. but not sure  ho to adjust "//ps:Obj[TN/T"  I removed the ps: but that did not help..  This is where I lack in the navigation understanding of XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Each* named element in an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query must use the appropriate *namespace prefix*.**

Therefore, for instance, replace:

```vb
Set customObjects = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ps:Obj[TN/T='System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject']")
```

with (note the `ps:` prefix in *all* element names):

```vb
Set customObjects = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ps:Obj[ps:TN/ps:T='System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject']")
```

The same applies analogously to the subsequent `.SelectSingleNode()` calls.

To put it all together:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False

' Load the PowerShell XML content
xmlDoc.Load "C:\path\to\your\file.xml"

If xmlDoc.ParseError = 0 Then
    ' Use the namespace in XPath queries
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ps='http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04'"

    ' Select all PSCustomObject elements
    Set customObjects = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ps:Obj[ps:TN/ps:T='System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject']")

    ' Iterate through PSCustomObject elements
    For Each customObject In customObjects
        ' Access properties within the PSCustomObject
        refNumAttr = customObject.SelectSingleNode("ps:MS/ps:I32[@N='RefNum']").Text
        nameAttr = customObject.SelectSingleNode("ps:MS/ps:S[@N='Name']").Text
        typeAttr = customObject.SelectSingleNode("ps:MS/ps:S[@N='Type']").Text

        ' Display the parsed properties
        Wscript.Echo ("RefNum: " & refNumAttr)
        Wscript.Echo ("Name: " & nameAttr)
        Wscript.Echo ("Type: " & typeAttr)
    Next
Else
    ' Handle XML parsing error
    Wscript.Echo ("Error loading PowerShell XML: " & xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason)
End If
```

Note:

- To run the code in Excel's Visual Basic for Application (*VBA*) code editor, with diagnostic output to the Immediate Window, replace `Wscript.Echo` with `Debug.Print`.

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much.  I do have a Id-10_t Question.   How did you know to use the ps:. I don't see if in the XML Path.

Comment: is it because I used it here ""xmlns:ps=" that I carry that on?

Comment: @OldManWithTime: Yes, it is because you used `:ps` in `xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:ps=..."` that you have to use prefix `ps:` in your XPath queries. This prefix is self-chosen, and needn't be the same as in the input document - only the URIs must be the same.

Comment: looks like the XML did not follow the same format.  I tried to paste it, but it looks bad and I exceed the char count.  the first object has '<TN RefId="0">' and the rest have '<TNRef RefId="0"/>'  I am not sure how you navigate that..

Comment: @OldManWithTime: Navigating this recursive format with internal cross references will be far from trivial, which is why I originally suggested using PowerShell. You _can_ call it from VBScript/VBA, but it will be _slow_, and you can only return _text_ - though using a structured text format may help. If you're calling a PowerShell _script_ file, you may have to use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to allow execution (though a GPO-based policy may prevent that).

Comment: O Well, Time for Plan b.  LOL Thanks